# How to set the header double click event in data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, styles

Is it possible to do the below (set the header double click event in data grid) in code behind? And if yes, how? Anything I searched did not show being possible to access the style of a data grid header!

```
<DataGrid ...> 
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnTableDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
```

Many thanks.

**Edit**

After other attempts, I also tried this in the constructor of the CustomDataGrid class derived from DataGrid:

```
        Style _style = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
        _style.BasedOn = Application.Current.Resources["DataGridColumnHeaderStyle"] as Style;
        _style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(MouseDoubleClickEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnTableDoubleClick)));
        this.ColumnHeaderStyle = _style;
```

If I well understood what I did this should add the double click event to the header style, but in fact it does nothing, meaning the handler is not called on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare style on `DataGridRowHeader`:

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                             Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

In case you are talking about column header. Replace `DataGridRowHeader` with `DataGridColumnHeader`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, because of speed I copied the wrong block of code. I actually meant DataGridColumnHeader. I updated the question. Anyway, teh problem is I would like to do this from code behind not from xaml and it does not seem to work.

Comment: So for that you need to show your code behind code which you have tried and doesn't work.

Comment: Why you are doing that in code behind? You have resource declared already in style. So, why not to declare event setter there only. Moreover, you can always do `BasedOn` from XAML as well.

Comment: because the style is a generic one defined at application level, hence I cannot have a handler declared in the style. I tried to define a "local" style at class level with BaseOn in XAML but this is also not working: if I define my own data grid class like "public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid" and use the <Style x:key="CustomDataGridColumnHeaderStyle" BaseOn="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" I am loosing all the settings in the other base styles for DataGrid (to be honest not sure why) and I would need to set explicitly every style I apply on the DataGrid - and there are many ...

Comment: No if style is declared at App level. You can always based on that style. It would be nice if you can post small sample code here replicating an issue because what you mentioned in question works. You are missing something here which can't be traced down with information provided in the question.